# Definability of a structure into another one: definition and sufficient condition to prove it

Tags: logic, model-theory

**Motivation** (*skippable content*).$\newcommand{\M}{\mathfrak{M}}$
$\newcommand{\L}{\mathscr{L}}$
I had difficulty to understand the definition in my lecture note of "structure definable to another one". Luckily, the [definition of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(model_theory)#Definition) (*they use interpretable for definable*) is very clear to me, however their definition is dual to the one of my lecture note (namely surjective $\to$ injective, preimage $\to$ image).

I tried to reformulate the definition in my lecture note in a dual way of the Wikipedia's one as follows:

> Let $\M$ be an $\L$-structure and $\M'$ be an $\L'$-structure.
> If there is an injection $\varphi : \M \hookrightarrow \M'$ such that
> $\varphi(M) \subseteq (M')^n$ (for some $n$) such that the $f^k$-image $f(X)$ of every
> subset $X \subseteq M^k$ definable without parameter is definable with parameters in $M'$.
> Then we say that $\M$ is *definable* in $\M'$ with parameters.

I also adapted [the sufficient condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(model_theory)#Definition) to prove that image preserve definability of definable sets of $\M$, namely:

> To show that the image of every definable-without-parameter set in $M$ is
> definable in $M'$ with parameters, it suffices to check that the images of the
> following definable sets:
>
> - the domain of $M$;
> - the diagonal of $M$;
> - every $\{c^\M\}$ for every constant $c$;
> - the graph of every function $f^\M$;
> - every relation $P^\M$.

But I realized that this condition may not be sufficient with my definition. Indeed, with Wikipedia's definition, as preimage preserves union, intersection and complement it suffices to prove that the preimage preserves the definable sets above to show that every definable sets are preserved by preimage (that's because the set of definable subsets is the smallest set containing above sets and closed under the Boolean operation aforementioned).

However, with my definition, even though an injective function's image preserves union and intersection, it doesn't preserve complement (it has to be also surjective). So I cannot ensure that, given a set $A$ definable in $\M$ such that $\varphi(A)$ is definable in $\M'$, $\varphi(A^C)$ is definable in $\M'$.

<s>**Question**: Is my definition correct? If not, is it possible to adapt it as my attempt?</s>

*EDIT*: As suggested @tomasz in comment, I confused definability and interpretability. So my question turned to be

**Question**: What's the correct definition of definability ?

*EDIT 2*:

This is my new phrasing of the definition, please tell me if it is correct:
$\newcommand{\M}{\mathfrak{M}}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathfrak{N}}$
$\newcommand{\Def}{\mathsf{Def}}$

> **Definition** (*Definability and interdefinability*).
> Let $\M$ be an $\L_1$-structure and $\N$ an $\L_2$-structure.
> If there is an injection $\varphi: \Def(\M, M) \hookrightarrow \Def(\N, N)$
> such that
>
> - $\varphi(M) \subseteq N^k$, for some $k$, can be endowed with an
>   $\L_1$-structure $\M'$ isomorphic to $\M$;
> - symbols interpreted in $\M'$ (*i.e.* $\{c^{\M'}\}, R^{\M'}$ and graph of $f^{\M'}$)
>   are definable in $\N$.
>
> Then we say that $\M$ is *definable* in $\N$ with parameters.
> If $\M$ and $\N$ are definable in each other, with say that they are *interdefinable*.

($\Def(\M, M)$ is the set of subsets $M$-definable in $\M$).

Comment: Interpretable is not exactly the same as definable. Usually, "interpretable in $M$" means "definable in $M^{eq}$".

Comment: @tomasz Sorry, I'm really new in Model theory, so not really sure what are you referring. Are you suggesting that the definition of Wikipedia should be the one of "$\mathfrak{M}$ definable in $\mathfrak{M}'$"? I'm not sure either what $M^{\rm eq}$ refers to. The $(\mathscr{L} \cup \{=\})$-expansion of $\mathfrak{M}$?

Comment: No, the definition on Wikipedia is correct (as far as I can tell) in that it does describe interpretability (not definability) as I understand it. The difference is that for "definable" you would need the interpretation function to be injective (although the domain should still be allowed to be a subset of $M^n$ for some $n>1$, but I guess that is a matter of convention).

Comment: $M^{\mathrm{eq}}$ is the expansion of $M$ by imaginary sorts.

Comment: As for your definition, the obvious problem is that the domain of $\varphi$ should be a definable set, rather than the model.

Comment: OK, thanks. Do you have in mind a reference covering definability/interdefinability with some examples ?

Comment: Sorry, nothing that would immediately come to mind. Maybe you should just check some standard model theory textbooks.